# Don't understand the return code from a forfiles command embedded in a for

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to cycle through a list of users (`office_id_list_%YY_MM_DD%\%%`) that I have for each office (office_list.txt) and create a file when files newer that a date (`%3`) are found.  The below code wasn't working so I decided to echo the errorlevel and found that it was  always `-1073741510` (working on a Windows 2003 machine).  Ultimately, I'm trying to identify user home directories(organized by office) that have not been modified since a given date.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (U:\sysmon\u_cleanup\office_list.txt) do (
  if not exist u:\sysmon\u_cleanup\results\%%i mkdir u:\sysmon\u_cleanup\results\%%i
  for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%j in (U:\sysmon\u_cleanup\results\office_lists_%YY_MM_DD%\%%i_dir_list_%YY_MM_DD%_final.txt) do (
    forfiles /P %1%%i\%%j /S /D +%3 /C "cmd /c if %errorlevel% == 0 echo ** Do not Archive - Found files modified after %3 > U:\sysmon\u_cleanup\results\%%i\%%j_%YY_MM_DD%.txt"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `/V:on` option to `cmd` and use `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%` which turns on delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the main problem is the part `cmd /c if %errorlevel% == 0`, it expands the errorlevel before any of your commands are executed.

Normally delayed expansion is the choice, but here it doesn't work(or as Joey mentioned, with /V:on), because it is in a new cmd context.

Here you could use it this way `cmd /c if %%errorlevel%% == 0`, so if the complete block is parsed the first time, the part is expanded to `cmd /c if %errorlevel% == 0`, and this is expanded a second time, when the `cmd /c` is executed.

And you could beautifying the code a bit

```
set "officePath=U:\sysmon\u_cleanup"
set "officeDatePath=%officePath%\results\office_lists_%YY_MM_DD%"
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ("%officePath%\office_list.txt") do (
    if not exist "%officePath%\results\%%i" (
        mkdir "%officePath%\results\%%i"
    )
    for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%j in ("%officeDatePath%\%%i_dir_list_%YY_MM_DD%_final.txt") do (
        forfiles /P %1%%i\%%j /S /D +%3 /C "cmd /c if %%errorlevel%% == 0 echo ** Do not Archive - Found files modified after %3 > %officePath%\results\%%i\%%j_%YY_MM_DD%.txt"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Also worked. Thanks for the code beautification tips. I do like to streamline if possible but it seems when I try, I introduce more issues. Do you have any good reference material on things like delayed expansion or how dos interprets variables (maybe load-time and run-time discussion ). Either way, thanks much.

Comment: @jim: For beginners and also experts [Dostips.com](http://www.dostips.com), for understanding how batch works (experts) [how cmd parse one line delayed vs percent vs %%var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)